C# - How do I track a dynamic variable and add it to a running total in a do loop?
Alright so the code looks like this:
price = 0;
do
{
count = 1;
Console.Write("              Enter price for item {0}", count);
price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
count++;

} while (price != -1);

'count' is meant to keep track of how many user inputs have been offered, price is meant to change based on user input. However, I have another variable called 'total' that needs to be calculated when the user enters -1 and the loop ends, and 'total' is meant to be the total value of each user input of 'price'. I'm sure this is a very basic question but I cannot figure out how to store the value of price and add it all together at the end.

You either add to it as you go (total=total+price on every pass of the loop) or you store all the inputs in a list as you go and add them up into being the total at the end. You cannot set the total at the end without remembering all the inputs, because price is a sole number; it doesn't remember every input it ever saw

@flackoverstow Wow I feel like an idiot. I thought the declaration of price and total at the beginning of the loop would trigger over and over, erasing the progress and resetting both on each subsequent pass. I'll give this a shot, thank you.
